# Specifying dates in my query doesn't produce any results/records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to query my table against two dates and retrieve the records within them.

I declare my variables like so;

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime;
DECLARE @EndDate datetime;
```

And set my variables like so;

```
SET @StartDate = 2012-08-01;
SET @EndDate = 2012-08-02;
```

My WHERE clause;

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN  @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

No records are displayed when the query is executed, what's my mistake? I've tried adding a time to the date but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this instead

```
SET @StartDate = '2012-08-01'; SET @EndDate = '2012-08-02';
```

or better

```
SET @StartDate = Convert(datetime,'2012-08-01',120); 
SET @EndDate = Convert(datetime,'2012-08-02',120);
```

This will return any data on 1 Aug, or anything marked as midnight on 2-Aug. It won't return anything marked as eg: 9am on 2-Aug

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime
SELECT @StartDate = '20120801', @EndDate = '20120802'

SELECT * from TableName
WHER Date between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with

```
WHERE Date >= @StartDate AND Date <= @EndDate
```

Comment: The problem isn't the WHERE clause. See the other answers. `SET @startDate = 2012-08-01` is the problem; `2012-08-01` is an integer calculation, it should be `'2012-08-01'` - as per the other answers here before yours.